# Filtering out tags from beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking at a table on a website and I basically need to scan through every tenth item in the table, then export these values to a csv for a project. This is what I'm doing now:

```
prices = []
    for td in soup.findAll('tr'):
    tds = soup.findAll('td')
    prices.append(tds[2::10])
```

but this prints out all of the td tags. I tried to call:

```
prices = []
    for td in soup.findAll('tr'):
    tds = soup.findAll('td')
    print(tds[2::10].text)
```

but when I do that I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tds = soup.findAll('td')` is a list. You can try iterating over the list and getting your required output.

**Ex:**

```
tds = soup.findAll('td')[2::10]
for td in tds:
    print(td.text)
```